# decking overhang

Tags: floor

I am building a 8x8 deck with stairs coming from landing on north side to landing on n.w. corner then along the west side. inspector said if I can show that running the 6 2x8 joist full length 12 ft. overhanging 4ft will support 100lbs per sq. foot I would not need additional post to support the 4ft. x 4ft. landing. would like some type of data to show this to be plenty. thanks for your help. need to know asap

Comment: If I figure it right, are you planning on putting 1600 lbs on the overhang?

Comment: 8 adults in a 4x8 area with railings on three sides isn't an unforeseeable circumstance.

Comment: Doesn't your inspector want an engineer to show that it can support the load? Would he really accept whatever data you can dig up on the internet?

Comment: That's an absurdly long cantilever by today's standards. Around here you can't cantilever more than about 18" even with 2x12s (1.5 x joist height). You'll need to use taller joists there or a redesign. One option might be to drop taller joists by notching the opposite ends, which are presumably supported by joist hangers, and lower the beam in that area.